# Google Chrome notifications don't show

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I want send notification by Google Chrome Extension 
**Manifest**

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Test",
      "default_icon": "test_16x16.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
chrome.notifications.create(
    'name-for-notification',{   
    type: 'basic', 
    iconUrl: 'image.jpeg', 
    title: "This is a notification", 
    message: "hello there!" 
    },

function() {} 

);
});]
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Could you add more details like what things have you tried, what error are you getting if any etc.

Comment: You would have some sort of error in the background page. Please check for that.